# Not running - Active: active (exited)

Tags: postgresql, linux-mint

Linux Mint 20.2

Postgresql 9.6.

Steps:

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql.service
```

Result:

```
Synchronizing state of postgresql.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable postgresql
```

Then restart service like this:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

And when check status like this:

```
service postgresql status
```

I get this:

```
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2021-08-04 17:33:34 EEST; 47s ago
    Process: 29261 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 29261 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Why service is **EXITED** ?

here content of `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log`

```
2021-08-05 14:59:14.739 EEST [116538] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-08-05 14:59:13 EEST
2021-08-05 14:59:14.741 EEST [116538] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2021-08-05 14:59:14.746 EEST [116537] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-08-05 14:59:14.746 EEST [116542] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2021-08-05 14:59:15.210 EEST [116544] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2021-08-05 14:59:55.996 EEST [116537] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2021-08-05 14:59:55.996 EEST [116537] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2021-08-05 14:59:55.997 EEST [116542] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2021-08-05 14:59:55.998 EEST [116539] LOG:  shutting down
2021-08-05 14:59:56.037 EEST [116537] LOG:  database system is shut down
2021-08-05 14:59:57.069 EEST [119294] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-08-05 14:59:56 EEST
2021-08-05 14:59:57.072 EEST [119294] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2021-08-05 14:59:57.073 EEST [119299] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2021-08-05 14:59:57.073 EEST [119290] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-08-05 14:59:57.549 EEST [119301] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2021-08-05 15:03:46.004 EEST [119290] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2021-08-05 15:03:46.004 EEST [119290] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2021-08-05 15:03:46.004 EEST [119299] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2021-08-05 15:03:46.005 EEST [119296] LOG:  shutting down
2021-08-05 15:03:46.018 EEST [119290] LOG:  database system is shut down
2021-08-05 15:03:47.070 EEST [119631] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-08-05 15:03:46 EEST
2021-08-05 15:03:47.072 EEST [119631] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2021-08-05 15:03:47.074 EEST [119630] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-08-05 15:03:47.074 EEST [119639] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2021-08-05 15:03:47.557 EEST [119642] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

here another command:

```
pg_lsclusters

Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.6 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

one more command:

```
sudo pg_isready
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - accepting connections
```

Comment: The log file knows, while we do not.

Comment: @jjanes where I can find this log file?

Comment: as I told you in the chat and in your other question: the log file knows what's going on. I can't say where it is installed in your system, but you can search for "postgresql log path linux mint".. certainly you'll find something useful. cheers

Comment: On ubuntu, it is usually shown by `pg_lsclusters`.  I would assume mint is similar.

Comment: It is showing as exited because the `postgresql` service is a bootstrap process that starts the actual Postgres process. Try something like: `sudo service postgresql@9.6-main status`(you can Tab complete after typing postgresql to get options). `pg_lsclusters` will show you what is running also. How did you install Postgres?

Comment: @jjanes "pg_lsclusters" - result is nothing. Only this "Ver Cluster Port Status Owner Data directory Log file"

Comment: @AdrianKlaver "sudo service postgresql@9.6-main status" - result is " postgresql@9.6-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 9.6-main
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
"

Comment: Please add to your question how you installed Postgres. In meantime look in: `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log` and add any relevant error messages to your question, NOT IN comment.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver In my host not exist folder "/var/log/postgresql/"

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I was add file content of file /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log in my post

Comment: The contents of the log file and the result of `pg_lsclusters` and `pg_isready` are confusing. The log shows the server shutting down at rapid intervals. Is that you doing a shutdown? If not look at the system logs to see if something else is. Also are the monitoring commands being done at a different time then the look at the log file?

Answer (score 9):

Ubuntu 22.04

```
sudo apt install -y libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Here is the result

```
$ systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor    preset: enabled)
 Active: active (exited) since Sun 2022-08-14 14:49:01 CEST; 19min ago
 Main PID: 56596 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    CPU: 5ms

 Aug 14 14:49:01 MYHOSTNAME systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
 Aug 14 14:49:01 MYHOSTNAME systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.

$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.4 (Ubuntu 14.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)

$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
14  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log

$ systemctl status postgresql@14-main
● postgresql@14-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 14-main
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-08-14 14:49:01 CEST; 28min ago
Main PID: 56568 (postgres)
  Tasks: 7 (limit: 19013)
 Memory: 28.8M
    CPU: 1.287s
 CGroup: /system.slice/system-postgresql.slice/postgresql@14-main.service
         ├─56568 /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/14/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf
         ├─56570 "postgres: 14/main: checkpointer " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" >
         ├─56571 "postgres: 14/main: background writer " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
         ├─56572 "postgres: 14/main: walwriter " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" >
         ├─56573 "postgres: 14/main: autovacuum launcher " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "">
         ├─56574 "postgres: 14/main: stats collector " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" >
         └─56575 "postgres: 14/main: logical replication launcher " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "">
```

So In your case : **systemctl status postgresql@9.6-main** should display postgres active and running

Comment: Any idea why it's implemented as a separate service?